# Синхронизация коллекций HashSet java

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть две коллекции:

```
Set<Position> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<Position> set2 = new HashSet<>();
```

и класс Position:

```
public class Position {
    protected String depcode;
    protected String depjob;
    protected String description;

    public Position(String depcode, String depjob, String description) {
        this.depcode = depcode;
        this.depjob = depjob;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDepcode() {
        return depcode;
    }

    public void setDepcode(String depcode) {
        this.depcode = depcode;
    }

    public String getDepjob() {
        return depjob;
    }

    public void setDepjob(String depjob) {
        this.depjob = depjob;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Необходимо сравнить и синхронизовать set1 по set2. Eсли элементов в set1 больше чем в set2, то лишние данные добавить в коллекцию toDelete. Если меньше, в коллекцию tpAdd, а также измененные добавить в toUpdate.

```
Set<Position> toDelete = new HashSet<>();
Set<Position> toAdd = new HashSet<>();
Set<Position> toUpdate = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос, и с чем у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Достаточно странно, на мой взгляд, добавлять в `toDelete` и в `toAdd` на основе количества элементов в коллекциях, а не на основе различий между ними.

Comment: Добавлять нужно по различиям согласен. Необходимо сделать это методом equals. Вопрос в том, как вытащить эту разницу в коллекциях. Я прошу не выполнить, а подсказать как это сделать

Comment: Рекомендую почитать Джошуа Боха "Java. Эффективное программирование", 2-е издание (Joshua Bloch. Effective Java), а именно: глава 3, статьи 8-9, заодно и про всякие нюансы узнаете. И вообще, эту книгу настоятельно рекоммендую всю изучить.

Comment: @Kh.Bu так вот у вас в тексте вопроса есть только задание и нет ни слова про то, в чём сам вопрос. Если нужно сделать с помощью `equals`, то можно циклом в цикле: во внешнем цикле пробегаетесь по элементам одной коллекции, во внутреннем - по другой. И, собственно, сравниваете элементы. Один такой цикл циклов для add, другой - для delete. Какие элементы должны попадать в update - непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть необходимость проверять на update, то одним equals не обойтись. Чтобы понимать, что объект "апдейтнулся", необходимо присвоить ему однозначный идентификатор и выполнять сравнение уже по нему. Т.е. как я понял depcode и есть этот идентификатор.

Обновленный класс Position и класс-обертка результирующих коллекций:

```
static final class Position {
    //Мне кажется не очень правильным оставлять возможность менять идентификатор объекта!
    //Поэтому я удалил set метод и сделал значение final, т.е. константой.
    protected final String depcode;
    protected String depjob;
    protected String description;

    public Position(String depcode, String depjob, String description) {
        this.depcode = depcode;
        this.depjob = depjob;
        this.description = description;
    }
    //Здесь сравнение идет только по идентификатору
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Position)) return false;

        Position position = (Position) o;

        return getDepcode().equals(position.getDepcode());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getDepcode().hashCode();
    }
    //Доп. метод для сравнения остальных данных класса
    public boolean otherEquals(Position p){
        return this.getDepjob().equals(p.getDepjob()) && this.getDescription().equals(p.getDescription());
    }

    public String getDepcode() {
        return depcode;
    }

    public String getDepjob() {
        return depjob;
    }

    public void setDepjob(String depjob) {
        this.depjob = depjob;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Position{" +
                "depcode='" + depcode + '\'' +
                ", depjob='" + depjob + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

//Класс-обертка для результата
static final class Delta{
    final Collection<Position> added;
    final Collection<Position> deleted;
    final Collection<Position> updated;

    public Delta(Collection<Position> added, Collection<Position> deleted, Collection<Position> updated) {
        this.added = added;
        this.deleted = deleted;
        this.updated = updated;
    }
}
```

Метод для получения "дельты":

```
public static Delta getDelta(Set<Position> from, Set<Position> to){
    //Копируем списки из исходных.
    //Если данные из старого больше не нужны, то его копирование можно пропустить
    Set<Position> fromCopy = new HashSet<>(from);
    Set<Position> toCopy = new HashSet<>(to);

    Collection<Position> updated = null;
    //Получаем итераторы. Работаем с ними, потому, что будем удалять из списков
    final Iterator<Position> fromIterator = fromCopy.iterator();
    //Проходим по старым данным
    while (fromIterator.hasNext()){
        //Флаг того, что совпадение было найдено
        boolean found = false;
        final Position fromPos = fromIterator.next();
        final Iterator<Position> toIterator = toCopy.iterator();
        while (toIterator.hasNext()){
            final Position toPos = toIterator.next();
            //Если совпадают идентификаторы
            if (fromPos.equals(toPos)) {
                //При этом, если не совпадает содержание
                if (!fromPos.otherEquals(toPos)){
                    //Если список апдейтов еще не инициализирован, то делам это
                    if (updated == null) updated = new ArrayList<>();
                    //Добавляем значение
                    updated.add(toPos);
                    //Удаляем это значение из списка по которому проходим, т.к. оно нам больше не понадобится.
                    //И в конце, в данном списке останутся только added элементы
                    toIterator.remove();
                }                   
                //Устанавливаем флаг, чтобы удалить значение из списка from.
                //Получается, что в конечном счете в данном списке останутся только deleted элементы
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) fromIterator.remove();
    }
    //Проверяем, что хоть что-то осталось в списках
    //Если нет, то передаем специальный пустой список, чтобы занимать меньше места
    if (fromCopy.isEmpty()) fromCopy = Collections.emptySet();
    if (toCopy.isEmpty()) toCopy = Collections.emptySet();
    if (updated == null) updated = Collections.emptySet();

    return new Delta(toCopy,fromCopy,updated);

}
```

Тестируем:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Position old1 = new Position("1","some","desc");
    Position old2 = new Position("2","some1","desc1");
    Position old3 = new Position("3","some2","desc2");

    Position new1 = new Position("1","someNew","desc");
    Position new2 = new Position("2","some1","newDesc");
    Position new3 = new Position("4","some3","desc3");

    Set<Position> from = new HashSet<>();
    from.add(old1);from.add(old2);from.add(old3);

    Set<Position> to = new HashSet<>();
    to.add(new1);to.add(new2);to.add(new3);

    Delta d = getDelta(from,to);

    System.out.println("Added positions:");
    d.added.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("\nDeleted positions:");
    d.deleted.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("\nUpdated positions:");
    d.updated.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Результат:

> Added positions: Position{depcode='4', depjob='some3',
>   description='desc3'}
>
> Deleted positions: Position{depcode='3', depjob='some2',
>   description='desc2'}
>
> Updated positions: Position{depcode='1', depjob='someNew',
>   description='desc'} Position{depcode='2', depjob='some1',
>   description='newDesc'}

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Четко и доходчиво)

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось следующее решение:

```
Set<Position> toDelete = Collections.emptySet();
Set<Position> toAdd = Collections.emptySet();
Set<Position> toUpdate = new HashSet<>();

//ищем записи которые не равны между собой 
//но у которых совпадает, хотя бы одно поле
for (Position oldPos : oldPositions)
    for (Position newPos : newPositions)
        if (!oldPos.equals(newPos) && oldPos.otherEquals(newPos))
             toUpdate.add(oldPos);

//ищем записи содержащиеся только
//в множестве "старых" записей
Set<Position> buffer = new HashSet<>(oldPositions);
if (buffer.removeAll(newPositions)) {
    buffer.removeAll(toUpdate);
    toDelete = buffer;
}

//ищем записи содержащиеся только
//в множестве "новых" записей
//удаляем из них те, которые добавлены на "обновление"
buffer = new HashSet<>(newPositions);
if (buffer.removeAll(oldPositions)) {
   buffer.removeIf(position -> toUpdate.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.otherEquals(position)));
   toAdd = buffer;
}

System.out.println("for add: " + toAdd);
System.out.println("for delete: " + toDelete);
System.out.println("for update: " + toUpdate);
```

В классе `Position` нужно переопределить методы `hashCode` и `equals` для корректной работы `HashSet`

```
class Position {
    String depcode;
    String depjob;
    String description;

   //other methods       

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Position position = (Position) o;

        if (depcode != null ? !depcode.equals(position.depcode) : position.depcode != null) return false;
        if (depjob != null ? !depjob.equals(position.depjob) : position.depjob != null) return false;
        return description != null ? description.equals(position.description) : position.description == null;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
        int result = depcode != null ? depcode.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (depjob != null ? depjob.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
   }

   public boolean otherEquals(Position other) {
        return Objects.equals(this.depcode, other.depcode)
                || Objects.equals(this.depjob, other.depjob)
                || Objects.equals(this.description, other.description);
   }
}
```

Тест:

```
Position n1 = new Position("1", "s1", "desc1");
Position n2 = new Position("2", "s2", "desc2");
Position n3 = new Position("3", "s3", "desc3");
//запись на добавление
Position n4 = new Position("4", "s4", "this entry for add");
//запись на обновление
Position n5 = new Position("5", "s5", "new description");


Position o1 = new Position("1", "s1", "desc1");
Position o2 = new Position("2", "s2", "desc2");
Position o3 = new Position("3", "s3", "desc3");
//запись на обновление
Position o5 = new Position("5", "s5", "old description");
//запись на удаление
Position o4 = new Position("6", "s6", "this entry for remove");
```

Вывод будет следующий:

> for add: [Position{depcode='4', depjob='s4', description='this entry for add'}]
>   for delete: [Position{depcode='6', depjob='s6', description='this entry for remove'}]
>   for update: [Position{depcode='5', depjob='s5', description='old description'}]